# ¿Cómo cambiar el funcionamiento del menú de navegación en función del tamaño/resolución de la pantalla?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap, scroll

Tengo un menú de navegación el cual, si tengo pantallas menores a 1024, los índices los agrupo en un hamburger icon. Este menú en un navegador web en PC lo tengo de tal manera que al hacer scroll down desaparece, y reaparece al pasar el mouse por el top de la página, escondiendose otra vez si el mouse deja de estar en el top.

A partir de esto, lo que intento hacer es lo siguiente:

En pantallas menores a 1024(cuando los índices se agrupan en un hamburger icon), quiero que el menú pase de mostrarse como lo hace ahora, a que se muestre al hacer scroll up y desaparezca al hacer scroll down.

Manteniendo así las 2 funcionalidades, para dispositivos grandes usar la opción que ya tengo, y para más pequeños usar la que quiero implementar.

Muchas gracias por adelantado. Un saludo.

Dejo el código que pienso es relevante y que se refiere a la pregunta:

```css
.cabecera{
 width: auto;
 height: 193px;
 background-color: #4a4a4a/*19*/;
 font-weight: 300px;
 line-height: 1 !important;
 padding-top: 0px;
 z-index: 10000;
 
 position: fixed !important;
}

/*Para el hamburger Icon*/
.hamburgerContainer {
top:-50px;
display: inline-block;
cursor: pointer;
}
.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
width: 35px;
height: 5px;
background-color: #ffffff;
margin: 6px 0;
transition: 0.4s;
}
.change .bar1 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}
.change .bar2 {
opacity: 0;
}
.change .bar3 {
-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm col-sm-12 cabecera nav-down" style="padding:0px;">
    <div class="col-xl-2 col-6">
     <a href="#index">
      <img src="carpeta\logos\Logo-01.png" height="193px" width="193px">
     </a>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xl-4 d-none d-xl-block">
     <p class="cabeceraH">titulo<br>
     titulo<br>
     titulo<br>
     titulo</p>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xl-6 d-none d-xl-block" style="padding-bottom:150px;">
     <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="col-sm-3 nav-item">
       <a class="cabeceraH nav-link" href="#investigacion">Investigación</a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-sm-3 nav-item">
       <a class="cabeceraH nav-link" href="#miembros">Miembros</a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-sm-3 nav-item">
       <a class="cabeceraH nav-link" href="#docencia">Docencia</a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-sm-3 nav-item">
        <a class="cabeceraH nav-link" href="#contacto">Contacto</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    
    <div id="hamburger" class="col-6 d-xl-none hamburgerContainer" onclick="myFunction(this)">
     <div class="bar1"></div>
     <div class="bar2"></div>
     <div class="bar3"></div>
     <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
      <a class="cabeceraH nav-link" href="#investigacion">Investigación</a>
      <a class="cabeceraH nav-link" href="#miembros">Miembros</a>
      <a class="cabeceraH nav-link" href="#docencia">Docencia</a>
      <a class="cabeceraH nav-link" href="#contacto">Contacto</a>
      </div>
    </div>
        <nav>
        
        
        <!--Script para que el menú/navbar aparezca cuando poner el mouse en el top de la página-->
 <script>
 
  var mouseY = 0;

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
   mouseY = e.clientY || e.pageY;
    if(mouseY < 70) {
     $('nav').css({ top: '0' });
    }
  }, false);

  $(window).scroll(function() {
   var sc = ($(this).scrollTop() > 193) ? $('nav').css({ top: '-193px' }) : $('nav').css({ top: '0' });
  });

  $('nav').mouseout(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() > 193) {
    $('nav').css({ top: '-193px' });
   }
  });
 
 </script>
 
 <!--Para el hamburger Icon-->
 <script>
  function myFunction(x) {
   x.classList.toggle("change");
   document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }
 </script>
 
 <script>
  // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.hamburgerContainer')) {

   var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
     var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
     if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    document.getElementById("hamburger").classList.toggle("change");
     }
   }
    }
  }
 </script>
```

Estaba intentando hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```html
<!--Script para un scroll-menu en tablets y moviles(No funciona)-->
<script>
 $(window).resize(function() {
  if($(window).width() <= 1024){
  // Hide Header on on scroll down
   var didScroll;
   var lastScrollTop = 0;
   var delta = 5;
   var navbarHeight = $('nav').outerHeight();

   $(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
   });

   setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
     hasScrolled();
     didScroll = false;
    }
   }, 250);

   function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();
    
    // Make sure they scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
     return;
    
    // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
     // Scroll Down
     $('nav').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    } else {
     // Scroll Up
     if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('nav').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
     }
    }
    
    lastScrollTop = st;
   }
  }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Dónde está tu código?

Comment: Si añades el código de tu menú podremos ayudarte a encontrar una solución y será una mejor explicación de lo que estás intentando

Comment: Sí perdonad, es que el código es bastante engorroso. He editado la pregunta con lo que pienso que es relevante para entender lo que tengo.

Comment: Buenos días, quería comentar que ya lo he podido solucionar. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final los scripts que he usado para solucionarlo son los siguientes, por si a alguien le ayuda:

```html
<script>
 if($(window).width() > 1024){
  var mouseY = 0;

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
   mouseY = e.clientY || e.pageY;
    if(mouseY < 70) {
     $('nav').css({ top: '0' });
    }
  }, false);

  $(window).scroll(function() {
   var sc = ($(this).scrollTop() > 193) ? $('nav').css({ top: '-193px' }) : $('nav').css({ top: '0' });
  });

  $('nav').mouseout(function() {
   if($(window).scrollTop() > 193) {
    $('nav').css({ top: '-193px' });
   }
  });
 }
 </script>
 
 <!--Para el hamburger Icon-->
 <script>
  function myFunction(x) {
   x.classList.toggle("change");
   document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
  }
 </script>
 
 <script>
  // Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.hamburgerContainer')) {

   var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
   var i;
   for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
     var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
     if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
    document.getElementById("hamburger").classList.toggle("change");
     }
   }
    }
  }
 </script>
 
 <script>
  // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, slide down the navbar
  if($(window).width() <= 1024){
   var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
   window.onscroll = function() {
   var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
     if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.top = "0";
     } else {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.top = "-350px";
     }
     prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
   }
  }
 </script>
```